# extrasolar planet puzzler

Tags: probability

Based on the Kepler Space Observatory's findings, astronomer Seth Shostak estimated in 2011 that "within a thousand light-years of Earth," there are "at least 30,000" habitable planets (from this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_%28spacecraft%29)).

Using Dr. Shostak's estimate, within which radius R from Earth (in light years) can we be 95% certain there is at least one habitable planet?

Comment: This question needs additional assumptions in order to be answerable. Also, it deserves quite different answers depending on whether this is a homework/test question or if it's something you are genuinely interested in (and you therefore don't have to guess what a test creator intended).  Could you please tell us which it is?

Comment: Hi @whuber - not a homework question, just a topic I thought could use a little statistical rigor so no need to guess what a creator (or Creator :) ) intends as the answer. We can assume that habitable planets are distributed randomly throughout the volume of space with an average of 30,000 habitable planets per (1,000 ly)^3.

Comment: That's the kind of assumption you will need, Robert: thanks.  (BTW, the volume within one thousand lightyears of us is actually $4\pi/3 (1000^3)$ cubic lightyears, or a bit more than four times greater than you indicated.)  Now, in addition to this assumption, you will need to know (or guess) how Shostak made his estimate. For instance, it sounds like a lower prediction limit. Let's assume it's based on quantitative evidence and an unimpeachable model. We still need to know what confidence level he is using for that prediction--and he doesn't tell us, unfortunately.

Comment: @whuber, thank you for the correction. The 30,000 figure is a lower limit based on an extrapolation from the observed # of Earth-size worlds orbiting within the habitable zone of the main sequence stars sampled by the Kepler telescope. I couldn't say how accurate it is, but I thought for a "back of the envelope" estimate we could use it as a starting point.

Comment: Well, you know the rate is at least 30,000 per 4π/3(1000^3) 

It's easier to solve this if we say "what radius seems likely to have at most a 5% chance of having no habitable planets".  So don't look at "at least a 95% chance of 1", look at "at most a 5% chance of zero".

Answer (score 1):

Given we're dealing with an infrequent number of rare events, I think the Poisson process is a suitable solution for modeling the probabilities of extrasolar habitable planets.

Assuming a rate parameter of:
\begin{align} 
\lambda = \frac{\text{30,000 habitable planets}}{\frac {4 \pi(1,000 \text{ light years})^{ 3 }}{3 }}= 7.162 \times 10^{-6}
\end{align}

We have:

\begin{align} 
Pr(N(V+\Delta V)-N(V)=k) = \frac{(\lambda \Delta V)^{k} e^{-\lambda \Delta V}}{k!}
\end{align}

where k is the number of habitable planets in volume of space V. In our case, we'd like to solve for delta V in the Poisson process where P(k=0) = .05:
\begin{align} 
Pr(N(\Delta V)= 0) = .05 = e^{-\lambda \Delta V}
\end{align}

which gives us a volume of 418,282 cubic light years, equivalent to a sphere with radius of 46.2 light years centered on Earth. The *expected* number of habitable planets in a space of this volume is E(k) = 3.00.